# Can't turn on cron feature in Apache Zeppelin

Tags: cron, apache-zeppelin

I set property zeppelin.notebook.cron.enable to true in 
$ZEPPELIN_HOME/conf/zeppelin-site.xml to enable Cron feature.

I don't see the scheduler button. I'm using the docker image with tag 0.8.2

I checked both old and new notebooks

Comment: Hi, have you found the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same and manage to fix by doing / considering the ff:

1. Make sure that the `zeppelin.notebook.cron.enable` property is not inside a comment block

`<!-- GitHub configurations ...<property>...</property>... -->`

2. Value of `zeppelin.notebook.cron.folders` must be "/"

Hope this helps. Cheers!